# ASP.NET MVC loading of CSS based off of controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Within my site I have controller specific CSS files in addition to my master css file. For example

```
CSS/
    Prodcuts/
             product.css
             ...
    Blog/
        blog.css
        ...
    masterStyle.css
```

Where masterStyle.css is the master css file. What I want to do is when the user hits http://www.example.com/Products/ only mySite.css and all css files under Products get included. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your master page create the following placeholder **inside** the `<head>` section.

**Master page**

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Then inside your controller you should determine the list of .css files to be used as well as create a string that the views can use to easily place the content inside the page. Here is what I've used.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

    List<string> css = new List<string>()
    {
        "one.css",
        "two.css",
        "three.css",
        "four.css"
    };

    IList<string> cssTags = new List<string>();

    StringBuilder cssTag = new StringBuilder();

    css.ForEach(c =>
        {
            cssTag.AppendLine(string.Format(@"<link href=""{0}"" rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"" />", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(c)));
        });

    ViewData["css"] = cssTag.ToString();

    return View();
}
```

Then inside your view just place the follwing

**View**

```
<asp:Content ID="headContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<%= ViewData["css"] %>
</asp:Content>
```

The reason why I build up the list of .css inside the controller and then create a string that the view uses, is because I want the views to be as stupid as possible. An option would be to just place the list of .css files into the `ViewData` itself and then let the view do the looping and create the `link` tag, but it's better to do it elsewhere if possible.

Another option to using `ViewData` is to use a strongly typed view with a string property and then the view just picks that guy off. I personally don't use the `ViewData` dictionary. Instead all my views are strongly typed.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting idea, I did a quick search and found this, let me know if it works. I like the idea.

[ASP.NET MVC - style list item based on controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230705/asp-net-mvc-style-list-item-based-on-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Simple way could be to add a "custom.css" to each View subdirectory, and use this in the master page:

```
    <link href="/<%= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]%>/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Place ContentPlaceHolder in head section of your master page:

```
<head runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server" />
</head>
```

Then you can place your styles in this content in views (or create another master page that inherits for main master page for every controller):

```
<asp:Content ID="ContentHeadContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</asp:Content>
```